# How many files have changed?

Tags: git, bash, scripting

I want to know how many files I have changed in a repository.

Currently, I use this command, but it is too slow:

```
n = `git diff --name-only HEAD | wc -l | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`
```

I wrote a script which executes this command for each subdirectory. Every subdirectory is a git-repo. With this, I can easily see which repos have changes I need to commit.

How to get the same information, but faster? The command above needs noticable time to execute, for many repos this is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a count of the number of modified files, I'd go with `git ls-files`:

```
git ls-files -m -z | awk -v RS='\0' 'END { print NR }'
```

`-m` shows modified files and `-z` terminates each file name with a null character `\0`. Awk is then used to count the number of records. This is the safest option as it correctly handles file names containing weird characters such as newlines.

If you're not concerned about that, you could just go with this slightly more simple approach:

```
git ls-files -m | wc -l
```

Comment: Do you know what ls-files does internally different? I don't know if it's supposed to be faster, it feels the same to me. Anyway, thanks for mentioning a solution for weird file names.

Comment: @sinned I have no idea what `ls-files` does under the hood but it seems like the most direct way to ask git to list the modified files.

Answer (score 1):

`git status` seems faster (YMMV):

```
git status --porcelain | grep -cv '^??'
```

Comment: Do you know of any internals why this might be faster? For me, it *feels* slightly faster, but the main reason to use your command is it's shorter and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in finding if a repo has changes at all (not the exact count), this is probably the fastest I know:

```
git diff --quiet --exit-code
```

It will return `1` if there are changes, `0` otherwise.

I know that your original question mentions the number of commits, but if you only want to see changes, this is probably enough.